# Where did javax.xml.bind go in Java 9?

Tags: java, javax, javax.xml

I tried migrating my project from JDK 1.8 to Java 9, but it wouldn't compile. My project uses a lot of `javax.xml.bind.annotation` classes and it seems they are missing. Were they moved somewhere or deprecated?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j

Comment: [This Answer by bourgesl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48279048/642706) enabled JAXB 2.3.0 on Java 10 for me. Uses `org.glassfish.jaxb` rather than `com.sun.xml.bind`.

Answer (score 0):

This is marked for removal( and moved to module java.xml.bind), you can refer to documentation here:
[Java Docs API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java.xml.bind-summary.html#packages.summary)